# Compressing an archive of images does not reduce its size significantly

Tags: tar, compression, archive

I have lots of pictures to back up from my computer to an external hard drive. I want to make archives of all picture folders I want to back up and compress them to save space on my external drive. I tried to use `tar` with `gzip`, `bzip2` or `xz` compression, but the result was not what I expected. The compressed archive sizes were not very different from the source files.

I'm using Debian 11 with KDE Plasma. Most pictures are `jpeg` and `nef` (RAW) files.

I want to know what's going wrong. Why does the compression not significantly reduce the archive size?

Comment: This is normal. Image formats are not very compressible, and are often already compressed, so simply passing them through a compression tool like `gzip` which is not specifically designed for image data won't make much difference. If you want to compress image files, you need to change the image format. For example from JPG to PNG. Please [edit] your question and tell us i) what operating system you are using and ii) what image format your files are (jpeg? png? gif?).

Comment: Thanks @terdon that is what I thought. I updated my question to add details about the situation.

Comment: "For example from JPG to PNG" or in the opposite direction depending on the kind of pictures there are. My experience is that jpeg files of photos are already very compressed, and can only be further compressed by reducing the quality of the picture. Is that an option for you? I don't know the nef format, but would guess that you might convert them to a more efficient format losing some (but not too much) flexibility and/or quality. But please think twice, it can be worthwhile to get bigger (and maybe faster) backup drives to store what you have now without losing flexibility and/or quality.

Comment: Did you try with `zstd` ?

Comment: Your images are already compressed (NEF-files usually are also, you can setup this in the camera)

Comment: @thiblcr no, I didn't but I'll try this asap !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The essence of GZIP / 7Z algorithms lies in having **matching sequences of bytes** in the file contents. Hence they work well for document & data files but not media files. None of the image formats have that type of signature.

> JPEG uses the finest of mathematics to capture the essence of a picture in `less number of numbers`. See this detailed blog to learn more about this [beautiful format](https://yasoob.me/posts/understanding-and-writing-jpeg-decoder-in-python/). This is different trickery from what is in the scope of GZIP / 7Z.

JPEG, [NEF](https://onlinemanual.nikonimglib.com/d850/en/18_menu_guide_03_11.html) & other image formats are effectively a sequence of numbers. Before writing out the numbers to file, the sequence **is already encoded by DEFLATE / Huffman encoding**; which is what the zipping algorithms do.

Also, this does not work recursively; once `encoded /zipped` the byte sequences in the file representation become too random to find many matching sequences.